# В чем можно удобно рисовать большие таблицы в стиле Mind-карт?

Tags: excel, visio

Нужно нарисовать большую таблицу вроде такой: [https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Сравнение_командных_оболочек](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85_%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BA) (с цветовыми индикаторами, сортировками и т.д.)

Таблица обещает быть большой, список полей не определен, к тому же над таблицей предположительно будут работать разные люди, поэтому было бы желательно это как-то совместить с Mind-картами. К примеру, рисуем пару ветвей, в одной ветке записи вида "Функции", "Обработка исключений", а в другой "Bourne shell", "POSIX shell", затем делаем из этого сводную таблицу и заполняем. Что-то такое существует?

Желательно десктопное приложение (win32/linux), а не веб-интерфейс.

**Новое:**

Что значит удобно?

Это значит полноценное использование клавиатуры и хоткеев. Если мне надо куда-то целиться мышкой для добавления очередного пункта - оно мне не надо. До мышки еще дотянуться надо, а это долго.

Это значит, что отклик приложения должен быть мгновенным. Если я дал команду "новый пункт", то покажи его мне сейчас. Если ты покажешь мне его через 0.5 секунды, то я это считаю за тормоза и потому браузерные изделия не приветствуются

Я не должен искать, куда ввести новую информацию. И если есть горизонтальный скроллинг - это очень плохой сигнал. Ввод в традиционных редакторах вроде OOCalc/Excel превращается в постоянный скроллинг "где там та ячейка, куда я написать хотел".

**Новое:**

Нечто подобное было обнаружено в MindView: https://youtu.be/lHMOQaKrXeg - обратите внимание на поля часов и денег. Но данная реализация мне кажется жутко неудобной.

Comment: Я правильно понимаю, что вы хотите редактор дерева, на основе которого составляется таблица, столбцы которой соответствуют листьям этого дерева? Или что вы подразумевали под "большие таблицы в стиле Mind-карт"?

Comment: На основе разных ветвей которого составляется таблица. Разные проекции одного дерева, если угодно

Comment: Таблица двумерная, так что ветвей, видимо, две. И вы хотите иметь для каждой неупорядоченной пары ветвей отдельную таблицу, содержащую по строке/столбцу на лист и по значению для каждой пары строка/столбец. Похоже?

Comment: Да, именно так. Так делает Википедия, по моей ссылке - 5 разных таблиц с одинаковыми программами. Получается 5 сводных таблиц из одной ветки и 5 других.

Впрочем, я не настаиваю. Возможно, есть какой-то другой способ, это просто предположение, что так будет удобно.

Comment: Нет, существующего ПО такого вида я не видел, но написать такое, с виду, несложно. А то описание, что я сейчас из вас вытягивал, очень плохо угадывается из вопроса. Возможно, стоит его переписать.

Comment: Признаюсь честно, я сам очень смутно представляю то, что ищу сам. Вполне возможно, что существует более простой и очевидный способ рисования таблиц как по ссылке. Как оно должно выглядеть - я тоже не знаю, может это будет 3D/4D-куб/тессеракт, а может быть каждая строка должна разворачиваться в "карточку продукта" в плоском виде и представлять собой форму на весь экран - я не знаю как это должно быть, от того и не знаю, что и ищу, потому и толком переписать не могу, разве что добавил требования.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для таблицы вроде [https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Сравнение_командных_оболочек](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85_%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BA) (с цветовыми индикаторами, сортировками и т.д.) думаю Mind-карт необязателен, так как не трудно догадаться что таблица из себя представляет.

Если у вас данные готовы в текстовом виде, то можно будет создать файл в `csv` формате и потом открыть его в **Excel**'е. Что касается цветов, то думаю тут можно будет задавать условия для форматирования. Если это не вариант, то в таком случае думаю надо будет создать такое приложение самому, и оно не должно составить труда так как таблица у вас двумерная. Я подозреваю что трудно найти приложение который соответствует вашим требованиям если конечно вообще такое приложение есть.

Если вы поддерживаете идею создания приложения, то ниже я написал примерный сценарий простенького приложения которым Вам будет очень удобно пользоваться.

Для начала будут нужны две формы:

- Первая будет задавать количество колонок в таблице (кол-во столбцов не надо задавать так как оно может быть неопределенным) и именовать их. После этого автоматически должна создаться таблица с заголовками и с нулевым столбцом на рабочем пространстве (Workspace).
- Вторая должна открываться сочетанием клавишей типа **`Ctrl + N`** - Windows / Linux или **`Command + N`** - Mac OS X для добавления нового столбика. Эта форма должна быть очень удобной для заполнения данных при помощи только клавиатуры. (Переключение между полями клавишами **`Tab`** или **`Shift + Tab`**, **`Ctrl + Enter`** чтобы добавить новый столбик (после заполнения формы) и т.д. и т.п.)

Дальше пойдут формы для редактирования, дублирования и т.д. Удалить можно будет мышкой и/или сочетанием клавишей типа **`Ctrl + D`** - Windows / Linux или **`Command + D`** - Mac OS X.

Что касается Mind-карт, то в будущем можно будет добавить его как опцию или как плагин для приложения, то есть двигаться постепенно от простого к сложному.

Я являюсь Java программистом, и буду рад помочь Вам если вы решитесь реализовать этот проект на Java.

**PS**: Кстати, чтобы быстро перейти к нужной ячейки можно будет создать еще одно диалоговое окно которое открывается сочетанием клавишей типа **`Ctrl + G`** - Windows / Linux или **`Command + G`** - Mac OS X (**G** - от goto). Например, чтобы перейти к колонке 99 ряда 578 достаточно будет набрать текст `c99r578` и нажать **Enter**. То есть для каждого случая можно будет создать форму или диалоговое окно а также прикрепить сочетаний клавишей к этой форме.

Comment: Нет, данных у меня как раз нет, их и предполагается забивать. И я тоже склоняюсь к написанию приложения, правда я его вижу совершенно иначе: никаких форм в принципе, все происходит внутри единого рабочего пространства, которое можно скроллить и зумить, основу которого составляет обычное майнд-дерево, но с добавлением "листочков" со списком свойств, взятых из референс-веток, объявленных "листиками". Совместно писать, наверное, не буду, так как я очень ленивый, хочу готовое, и так куча других простаивающих проектов, плохо представляю создание ГУЯ на Жабке, да и вообще, предпочитаю больше Сишку.

Answer (score 3):

Попробуйте [XMind](http://www.xmind.net). Вот официальный [пример](https://xmindshare.s3.amazonaws.com/preview/gh8Z-DkoLWPX-32727.png) работы с таблицами.

Comment: Я очень давно работаю в XMind, этот пример есть в стандартных шаблонах, но вот как его сделать - я так и не понял. Я даже пытался найти видео-туториалы, но без успеха. Если есть мануалы - пожалуйста поделитесь. Встроенная справка не помогла.

Comment: @bukkojot, с точки зрения XMind таблица - это тоже дерево. Просто создаете дерево и у корневого элемента в свойствах меняете тип на "матрица".

Comment: А, ну это фактически просто стилевое представление. Я уж подумал, что есть какие-то другие варианты, такие как сводные таблицы (см. комментарии к вопросу). В любом случае, благодарю.

Answer (score 1):

Долгое время работал над проектом во **FreeMind** поддерживает экспорт и импорт различных форматов удобное перемещение по карте, [проект](https://github.com/Hellseher/mms) занял год работы.

Так же есть интересные конверторы для org-mode: ditaa, graphviz, PlantUML. Составляют дирграммы зависимостей из текстового файла.

Ссылки

- http://freemind.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Main_Page
- http://doc.norang.ca/org-mode.html#Publishing
- http://plantuml.com/
- http://www.graphviz.org/
- http://ditaa.sourceforge.net/
- http://orgmode.org/w/?p=org-mode.git;a=blob_plain;f=contrib/lisp/ox-freemind.el;hb=HEAD

Answer (score 0):

Есть не десктоп https://github.com/jgraph/mxgraph , возможно там найдете что-то нужное, это можно поставить себе на сервер.
А есть https://www.draw.io/ Простой интерфейс построения таблиц, диаграмм, графиков и всего всего что хочется. Десктопных альтернатив не знаю, не юзал

Comment: Я верю, что draw.io очень хороший инструмент, мне его скидывали мои коллеги, но я совершенно не понимаю, как в нем писать что-то сложное или большое. Нарисовать макет будущей программы мышкой - да, это понятно. А вот как в него удобно вбивать данные (критерии в первом посте), я так и не разобрался.